# How to script animation sequences in three.js?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm just getting started with three.js and I'm trying to make a very basic animation sequence. I've gone through the basic examples and see how to make objects move and spin, but I don't quite get how to structure a series of animation sequences.

For example...

Show 3 cubes and move them to a new position (ideally staggered a bit so as not to move at the same time)

THEN once they've all arrived, make two of them rotate an axis

THEN move them to a new position

etc...

There is no user interaction with what I'm building - it's just a series of movements that happen in sequence. Do people use something like Frame.js for this sort of thing or is there something simpler that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

Try out director.js - simple but effective.

https://github.com/zz85/ThreeLabs/blob/master/Director.js

There is somewhere a longer showcase, can't find the link, though.

Answer (score 0):

Tween.js is one choice:
https://github.com/sole/tween.js/.

Tutorial: 
http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/

Example:
http://learningthreejs.com/data/tweenjs_for_smooth_animation/tweenjs_for_smooth_animation.html

Comment: Yeah, I've played with Tween.js a little and it seems like a great way of timing individual movements, but not for sequencing a series of movements. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Well, you _can_ chain them, as in the example above.